# Trello API MANAGED_MEMBERS_REQUIRE_OWNEDBY_ENTERPRISE_ID error

Tags: trello, trelloapi

I'm using trello API to create organization and got this error

```
{
    "message": "MANAGED_MEMBERS_REQUIRE_OWNEDBY_ENTERPRISE_ID"
}
```

API call

```
POST https://api.trello.com/1/organizations?key=<key>&token=<token>&displayName="name"
```

Is there something wrong or I need to configure what to enable this action